# Moving a number in a zig zag pattern through a 2D array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 

//function protypes 
void gameBoard(); //prints board
void diceRoll();
void move();

//global variables
int roll;
int playerOne = 0; 
int playerTwo = 99;
int board[5][8] = {{33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40},
           {32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25},
           {17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
           {16,15,14,13,12,11,10, 9},
           { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

void diceRoll() { //asks player to input a charater to roll a dice 

    srand(time(0));
    roll = ((rand() % 6) + 1); //sets num to a random number between 1 and 6
   }

void gameBoard(){ // prints game board

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j){

        cout << board[i][j] << "  ";

        if (board[i][j] <= 8){
            cout << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}

} 

void move(int player, int& colPos, int& rowPos){

int tempCol; 
int tempRow;
int previous;

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){

    if(i % 2 == 1){

        tempCol = colPos + roll;
        colPos = tempCol; 
        tempCol = colPos - roll;

        if(colPos > 7){

            colPos = 7;
            rowPos--;
        }

    board[rowPos][colPos] = player; 

}

}

} 



int main() {    

int turn = 1;
int colPos1 = 0;
int rowPos2 = 4;
int colPos1 = 0;
int rowPos2 = 0; 

 while(winner == false){

    if(turn == 1){

        turn = 2;                                  //allows to switch back and forth bewteen turns
        diceRoll(player1);                        //rolls die
        move(playerOne, colPos1, rowPos2);
        gameBoard();                              //prints game board

    }else{

        turn = 1;                                   //allows to switch back and forth bewteen turns
        diceRoll(player2);                         //rolls die
        move(playerTwo, colPos2, rowPos2);
        gameBoard();                              //prints game board
                }

}


return 0;
}
```

So the code above is for a chutes and ladders game.  The program above should run without any errors.  I am almost done with this code but am having issues with the move function.  Here I am trying to move through a 2D array (the gameboard) as each player rolls a die.  There are two issues with the current code.  One after a player moves a space the space that they have previously left remains marked with the player.  In addition, once it goes across through an entire row it does not advance to the next row.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Note: I deleted a lot of code to make it more relevant to the question so it may have errors now.

Comment: Nobody is going to read that much code.

Comment: I just deleted some stuff to hopefully make it easier to read.

Comment: The trick is to remove code that is *not relevant to the problem*, leaving a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That isn't just for our convenience, it's a vital skill.

Comment: I took out even more stuff the formatting is a little off but all the code that is there is completely relevant.

Comment: @MitchellBerthelot The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"After a player moves a space the space that they have previously left remains marked with the player"**

In `move(int player, int& colPos, int& rowPos)`you already know which player you are updating and the current row and column position so you can use this as an opportunity to remove the mark on the current board piece and set it back to its default value e.g. once you step into `move` call something like `void ResetBoardPositition(int colPos, int rowPos)` and then update the new position with the player marker (alternatively you could not change the game board at all and just print the player position at the draw stage since you store their positions anyway)

**"Once it goes across through an entire row it does not advance to the next row"**

Your code isn't doing anything to take account of the fact you need to reverse direction every time you change rows. Each time you go past column 7 you just set the column to 7 and reduce the row. This means that your next roll will immediately take you past the column threshold again, set it to 7 and reduce the row count. You'll need to use some form of direction modifier for the roll so you have something like:

```
int direction = 1;
if (rowPos % 2 == 1)
    direction = -1;
tempCol = colPos + (roll * direction);
colPos = tempCol;
tempCol = colPos - (roll * direction);
```

Your check for the colPos would need to account for this too

```
if (colPos > 7) {

    colPos = 7;
    rowPos--;
} else if (colPos < 0) {
    colPos = 0;
    rowPos--;
}
```

There is also the issue that you do not account for the full roll here i.e. you set the column to the flat value meaning if you were on column 7, roll a 3 (which should put you at column 5 on the next row) you only move 1 space to the next row and stop there.

Hope these answer your main questions but I think there are some other logic issues going on here with your move code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, the reason the previous spaces still have that player's name in it is because that value is never reset after the player leaves. What you could do is create an int for the current position before the player gets there, move the player to the new position, and then set the old position to the int you created. I saw that your move function has an int previous, so just use that.

Second, when I ran it, the player would go through the first row, then just move up the last column. From what I saw, your move function only manipulates tempCol and colPos, but not tempRow or rowPos. Moving those will help the player move between the rows.

Also, on a side note, I saw a few things for you to look out for. You declared your function as

```
void diceRoll();
```

But when you defined it, you wrote it like this:

```
void diceRoll(string name) { //asks player to input a charater to roll a dice
```

I would suggest rather adding in your parameters when you declare it or just declare it and define it all at once.

Second, you probably haven't messed with it much, but the checkWinner() function doesn't change the value of winner.

```
if (pos1 || pos2 != board[0][7]) {
    winner == false;
}
else {
    winner == true;
}
```

Using == is for checking the value, not for assigning, so take out one of them.